# Is my package structure correct?

Tags: java, package

What should be the hierarchy of packages?

```
com.xyz.DAO
   IDAO          (interface) 
   IPersonDAO     (interface) 
   IDepartmentDAO  (interface) 

com.xyx.DAO.impl
   PersonDAO extends GenericDAO implements IPersonDAO
   DepartmentDAO extends GenericDAO implements DepartmentDAO
   GenericDAO implements IDAO   (abstract class)
   DAOFactory
```

Is this package structure appropriate?

Comment: I'd personally move `DAOFactory` one level higher to `com.xyz.DAO`.

Comment: I personally prefer the interfaces without "I" in front of the name, package following standard (no upper-case) and `DAO` implementation separated per persistence technology name for instance: `com.xyx.dao.hibernate` for hibernate implementation or `com.xyx.dao.jdbc` for JDBC DAOs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am actually against *layer-driven packaging* but instead I advice *feature-driven* approach:

```
com.xyz
   IDAO          (interface) 
   GenericDAO implemts IDAO   (abstract class)
   DAOFactory 
com.xyz.person
   IPersonDAO     (interface) 
   PersonDAO extends GenericDAO implements IPersonDAO
com.xyx.department
   IDepartmentDAO  (interface) 
   DepartmentDAO extends GenericDAO implemts DepartmentDAO
```

The reasoning is: you'll much more often want to have all classes related to *person* functionality in one place. Not often you need all DAO classes.

[image: UML]
<sub>(source: [yuml.me](https://yuml.me/eea37fef))</sub>

Comment: That's an interesting strategy... :)

Comment: Shoul IDepartmentDAO also extedn IDAO?

Comment: But . DepartmentDAO extends GenericDAO which implements IDAO and also IDepartmentDAO also extends IDAO.IS that not  a problem?

Comment: @user978939: I added a UML diagram to clarify your doubts

Comment: @all: Is it ok two have some classes as empty?Not in DAO context , bu in some other class heirarchy.Can i leave some classes with no spetial member methods?